# Implementing the TCP Authentication Option (TCP-AO)

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory, transport-protocol, authentication, rfc

Do any Cisco IOS/XE/XR systems support the updated TCP security option TCP-AO (option kind 29)?   It'd be nice to be able to use it.

It's defined in [RFC 5925](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5925), and is meant to obsolete [RFC 2385, "Protection of BGP Sessions via the TCP MD5 Signature Option"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2385).

I can't find any good references for it.  Even descriptions of BGP md5 authentication (tcp option kind 19) tend to gloss over details.

Is there a method to authenticate with AO instead of md5? Does Cisco even recognize it anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no for all three, and I don't think there is support in the popular gear in general.

Answer (score 0):

IOS-XR supports TCP-AO from 6.5.1 onwards